# Suppose $x$ is a limit point of $A \subset X$, then if $f: A \to Y$ is continuous, is it true that $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(A)$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

So I already know that a counterexample is $f(x) = c$ for $c$ is a constant, but I can't seem to prove this statement by contradiction, all I did was go back and forth.

> "*Proof*":
>
> If $f(x)$ were a limit point of $f(A)$, then $f(x) \in Cl[f(A)]$. So if we let $U - \{ f(x) \}$ to be a neighbourhood of $f(x)$, then by definition $$U - \{ f(x) \} \cap f(A) \neq \emptyset.$$
>
> Since $f$ is continuous, 
>   \begin{align}
> \implies f^{-1}(U - \{ f(x) \} \cap f(A)) &\neq f^{-1}(\emptyset) \\
> \implies f^{-1}(U - \{ f(x) \}) \cap f^{-1}(f(A)) &\neq \emptyset \\ 
> \implies f^{-1}(U) - f^{-1}\{ f(x) \}) \cap f^{-1}(f(A)) &\neq \emptyset \\
> \implies f^{-1}(U) - \{ x \} \cap A &\neq \emptyset \;(\text{because $A \subset f^{-1}f(A)$, similarly for $f(x) \subset f^{-1}\{ f(x) \}$})\\
> \end{align}
>
> So since the intersection is nonempty, if $y \in f^{-1}(U) - \{ x \} \cap A  \implies x \neq y\in f^{-1}(U)$ and $y \in f^{-1}f(A)$. Then $f(y) \in U \cap f(A)$

If I can just get a hint, it would be great. I kind of want some walkthrough or some comments instead of a solution.

**EDIT**: OKay I just located one mistake I made, 
$$f^{-1}(U) - f^{-1}\{ f(x) \}) \cap f^{-1}(f(A)) \neq \emptyset \implies f^{-1}(U) - \{ x \} \cap A \neq \emptyset$$

is wrong, but how can one obtain a contradiction from the previous line?

Comment: @Bryan, doesn't that just further imply that my proof is wrong…?

Comment: @Bryan, and I think you mean $f(cl(A)) \subset cl{f(A)}$

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not mention that $f$ is continuous.  You need that, otherwise the statement is not true.

If $x$ is a limit point of $A$, prove that $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(A)\subseteq Y$.

So, for example, take any $\varepsilon_0 > 0$.  You must prove that $\exists w\in Y$ with $|f(x) - w|<\varepsilon_0$.

Hint 1: Can you think of any candidates for $w$, given that you know that $f$ is continuous?

Hint 2: Given that $f$ is continuous, for any $\varepsilon$ whatsoever we choose, There exists a $\delta$ such that, if it should happen that $|x-u|<\delta$, then it will follow that $|f(x) - f(u)| < \varepsilon$, for all $u\in A$.  What if we choose $\varepsilon = \varepsilon_0$?  What follows then?

Hint 3: Choose $\varepsilon = \varepsilon_0$.  Then $\delta$ exists.  Therefore, it follows that for any $u\in A$ for which $|x-u| < \delta$ it will follow that $|f(x) - f(u)| < \varepsilon_0$; and thus for such $u$ it will follow that $f(u)$ is a neighborhood point of $f(x)$.  That is to say, if such $u$ can be found, then it will follow that $f(u)$ exists, and then we can set $w=f(u)$.  So, the final question: are there any $u$ such that $|x-u|<\delta$?  How do you know?

Comment: Um…$f(x)$ again? I see you are using the $\epsilon-\delta$equivalence to prove this. i hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Presumably we want a different element than $f(x)$, otherwise every point of $f(A)$ is a limit point.  ALSO, you will need to translate what I write here to topology --- talk about neighborhoods of a point instead of $|x-y|$ language, since your question is topological.  I am doing everything on the real numbers.

Comment: Um, regarding hint 2, it looks like $f(u) = w$, but I don't see how will this help me. It looks like I m still going back and forth.

Comment: I take it you mean to say $f(u)$ is in the neighbourhood of $f(x)$. Since $x$ is a limit point of $A$, the open set, $|x - u| < \delta$ must contain points other than $x$.

Comment: @sidht.  Correct!

Comment: @Itcomdata, but where is the contradiction…?

Answer (score 1):

From the get go, the answer is no, not always true, since it may be the case that no one point in $Y$ may be a limit point of $Y$ in some topologies.

You have to specify the topology on $Y$ to get a reasonable answer that is not too general. If $Y$ has, e.g., the discrete topology, then the answer is no; let $f(a)=b$. Then you can always find a ball $B(b,r); r>0$ with $B(b,r) \cap Y-{b}= \emptyset $. But, re the answer above, $X,Y$ may not be metrizable, but I don't have enough votes to comment.

Comment: Yes, my answer above assumes a metric.  But my answer above is a hint, as @sidht requested.  I am thinking about the case of the real numbers.  What I say can be generalized to "neighborhoods", which is the topological generalization of intervals.

Comment: Sorry to do this indirectly; I would have preferred to post it as a comment below your answer, but I don't have enough points to do that.

Comment: @user175665, that's actually a good point (refering to your comment about different topologies and the limit points). Looks like continuity is not enough.

Comment: @user175665, if $f$ is an open map (one that carries open sets in one space to the other), then is it okay?

Comment: @sidht: No; take a constant map from a discrete space to itself. Let me see if X is not discrete. And Y cannot be discrete for the image to be a limit point.

Comment: @user175665, oh because $\{ x \}$ is an open set itself, but $\{x\} - \{ x \} \cap O = \emptyset$ for any open set $O.$

Comment: @sidth: precisely. Maybe we can find a space in which convergent sequences are not necessarily eventually-constant, but let me see if I can make it more specific.

Comment: @sidht: I certainly am not very familiar with topology.  Hence my answer in the real numbers.  But, continuous functions map open sets to open sets, right?  And, if you have an open set in $A\subseteq X$ (whatever that may mean, depending on the topology), it will follow that $f(A)\subseteq Y$ will be open (whatever that may mean, depending on the topology).  And further, if $x\in A$ is a limit point, then there is at least another element $u$ 'near' $x$.  Given that $f$ is continuous, it would follow that it maps $x$ and $u$ 'near' each other.  Maybe $f$ has to be injective too?

Comment: @ltcomdata, no that's fine. It's easy to translate between the two, but I still don't see where my contradiction lies in my proof?

Comment: @ltcomdata : No, continuous functions do not map continuous sets to continuous sets; open maps (including homeomorphisms) do that. Take, e.g., (0,1), and consider its image in the Reals under $f(x)=x^2 $.